# Response code is 400 while using HttpURLConnection to POST in java for REST API

Tags: java, json, rest, httpurlconnection

I am a newbie to REST API's. I need to post to the website, but I get response code as 400 and content-type as text/plain

If I use Advanced REST Client Application of google, I get different results. The response code is 500 and the content-type is text/html.

Am I not ending the post data (query1) correctly? Is this the correct way of doing it? Do I need to use JAX-RS? Can someone please help? Appreciate it.

```html
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class RestfullAPIHttpURLConnection {
 
 @Test
 public static void postS() throws Exception {
  
  URL url;
  HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
  
  String urlParameters  = "email=tester0@xxx.com&profileName=Tester0&password=test&roleId=1";
  
  String email = "tester0@xxx.com";
  String profileName = "Tester0";
  String password = "test";
  int roleId = 1;
  
  String query = String.format("email=%s&profileName=%s&password=%s&roleId=%s", 
       (email), 
       URLEncoder.encode(profileName),
       URLEncoder.encode(password),
       (roleId));
  String query1="?";
  query1 = query1.concat(query);
  System.out.println("query1: " +query1);
  
  String type = "application/json";
  
  url = new URL("http://......com");
  connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
  
  connection.setDoOutput(true);
  connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
  connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", type );
  
  connection.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
  connection.setUseCaches( false );
  
  // creates an output stream on the connection and opens an OutputStreamWriter on it:
    
   OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
   Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8");
   
   // client's output is the server's input.
      writer.write(URLEncoder.encode(query1, "UTF-8"));
  
  
  String contentType=connection.getContentType();
  int responseCode=connection.getResponseCode();
  int len = connection.getContentLength();
  String rmsg = connection.getResponseMessage();
  
  System.out.println("ContentType: " +contentType);
  System.out.println("ResponseCode: " +responseCode);
  System.out.println("Content length: " +len);
  
  System.out.println("URL " + connection.getURL());
  System.out.println("Response msg: " + rmsg);
  
  
 }
 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Jersey Client](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html):

Here an example:

```
final WebTarget target = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("http://......com");

final WebTarget webTargetWithParams = target.queryParam("email", "tester0@xxx.com")
                                            .queryParam("profileName", "Tester0")
                                            .queryParam("password", "test")
                                            .queryParam("roleId", "1");

final Response response = webTargetWithParams.request().get();

System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
```

Comment: But, if the server respond 400 that means: you didn't send the right data to the server in the POST. In your code, I don't see what data are you sending.

Comment: Is jersey Client the only way to do this? This is the data I am sending to the server     String query = String.format("email=%s&profileName=%s&password=%s&roleId=%s", 
       (email), 
       URLEncoder.encode(profileName),
       URLEncoder.encode(password),
       (roleId));
  String query1="?";
  query1 = query1.concat(query);   OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
   Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8");
      writer.write(URLEncoder.encode(query1, "UTF-8"));